# Calling a jquery function inside an recently added jquery function

Tags: jquery, addition, document-ready

This title is a little confuse, but here is my problem:

I have this add function in jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

   var i = $('input').size() +1;

   $('#add').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

    $('.table1').before('<table class="new_table">
       '<tr>' +
         '<td colspan="4" class="subTitle_bar">' +
           '<spring:message code="phoneTable" /> '+ i +' '+ 
         '</td>' +
       '</tr>' +

       '<tr>' +
           '<td class="item">' +
              '<spring:message code="phoneNumber"  />' +
              '<span class="required">*</span>' +
           '</td>' +

           '<td colspan="3">' +
              '<input type="text" id="phone1' + i + '" name="phone1' + i + '" class="requiredField phone" />' +
           '</td>' +
       '</tr>');
     i++;
    });
```

and this class="requiredField phone" call this phone mask:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
$.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
$('.phone').mask('(99) 9999-9999');
```

So, when someone click to add a new field, this field have to have an mask, but it doesn't.

Comment: Please format your code. Now it is unreadable.

Comment: Sorry, can u read it now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to bind an event handler to the $('.phone') element on the Document ready event, while it doesn't exist in the DOM tree at the time you are trying to do so.

The solution is quite easy, you need to do something like this(untested code):

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

   var i = $('input').size() +1;

   $('#add').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

    $('.table1').before('<table class="new_table"><tr>' +
         '<td colspan="4" class="subTitle_bar">' +
           '<spring:message code="phoneTable" /> '+ i +' '+ 
         '</td>' +
       '</tr>' +

       '<tr>' +
           '<td class="item">' +
              '<spring:message code="phoneNumber"  />' +
              '<span class="required">*</span>' +
           '</td>' +

           '<td colspan="3">' +
              '<input type="text" id="phone1' + i + '" name="phone1' + i + '" class="requiredField phone" />' +
           '</td>' +
       '</tr>');
     i++;
     $.mask.definitions['~']='[+-]';
     $('.phone').mask('(99) 9999-9999');
    });
});
```

Since you are adding one element per each click it makes sense to use the :last filter or last function:

```
 $('.phone').filter(':last').mask('(99) 9999-9999');
```

Or

```
 $('.phone').last().mask('(99) 9999-9999');
```